# Is there a well known theory that states all particles are made up of smaller particles and so on and so forth?

Tags: particle-physics

I've contemplated, for some time, the possibility that all things are made up of smaller particles, and all smaller particles are made up of even smaller ones. I'm wondering if there are any popular theories that specifically support or deny this possibility.

Comment: What would the computer, the one that runs the simulation, be made of if matter doesn't really exist?

Comment: @AlfredCentauri I mean the same way you might build a particle simulation. The particles aren't real to you, and are all represented as data, but to the creatures within (let's say it's an extremely complex simulation), the particles and physics that define them would seem very much real.

Comment: But the universe is *all* there is.  When you write "the universe comes down to being a big computer simulation", you're essentially saying that *all there is* isn't real but a simulation.  Do you see any problem with that kind of thinking?

Comment: @AlfredCentauri the problem is in the wording. I should say "our universe" - after all, there are theories that state there are multiple universes, sort of. Specifically, I'm referring to all matter and physics related to The Big Bang. There is no way for us to know whether or not our universe is "all there is". Maybe the next universe is displayed on the monitor right next to the one that shows ours, in a 4D world as part of some kid's science experiment.

Comment: There are an infinity of conjectures that cannot be disproved such as, for example, that one is a brain in a vat.  What we observe is *the metaphysically given*.  Speculating about the unobservable is not physics.  Voting to close.

Comment: I deleted an inappropriate comment. Please remember that civility is expected at all times, as described in the help center.

Comment: Hey you that voted to close this question. many of you have already tried to answer in the comments, but then it became "non-mainstream". i have already answered this in that specific post in meta. The question asks exactly about the (any) "mainstream" theories that might have such an assumption.

Comment: And sth else, every "mainstream" theory before it became "mainstream", it had to start somewhere and continue from there. :p

Comment: @NikosM. yes the comments deviated into total speculation, but my question has remained clear from the start. I don't understand the close.

Comment: I have attempted an edit that may bring it to the mainstream, and remove this ``hold''. I think what the asker has hit upon is what we have also observed in the past 150 years, using science. Of course, metaphysics comes easily with these issues, but I think this question deserves better than being put on hold.

Comment: @New_new_newbie the original question included speculative comment, leading to close votes.

Comment: @DavidZ can my question be re-opened, since your edits?

Comment: @jt0dd note that the question was closed _after_ my edit, and also it was closed by five community members. It's not justified for me to reopen it unilaterally.

Answer (score 1):

i would say **no**.

1. There are (were?) indeed theories that state that some particles are not elementary but composite (assuming other elementary particles, etc..). For example it had been suggested that even quarks are not elementary particles. R. Feynman was quoted as saying, that "*..if it is shown that there is no underlying physical reality, but it is like the skins of an onion, then this is the  way it is..*" (not exact quote) (much of this is stated from memory, so if i am mistaken, feel free to say so)
2. By Planck limit (related to Planck's constant) there is a limit under which current experiments cannot go (planck scale). Of course this does not mean (necessarily) that this is the final scale, but combining the uncertainty relations, it means that the (phase-) space **cannot** be compressed arbitrarily (and at the same time). So this states a limit, a basis that reality is indeed *real* (if you like).
3. There is a difference between sub-consituting elementary particles (of presentlty found elementary particles) and the process of decaying of elementary particles into pairs or other compounds of other particles. (For example Higgs-like bosons decay into other particles, but this does not mean that they are constituted by them, or photons decay into pairs of electrons-positrons etc..)

Finally, no-one knows that the (final reality of the) universe is an infinite stack of turtles upon other turtles :)